# Very simple python client/server working, but strange delays

Tags: python, sockets, asynchronous

I am trying to learn how to use sockets and a useful asynchronous backend. I've started in python with asyncore. After reading various online posts I've written a very simple chat server and connection client, reproduced below.

It seems to work. I open a python interactive session and type

```
> import chatserver
> server = chatserver.EchoServer('localhost', 7667)
> server.serve()
```

Then I open another IPython interactive session and type

```
> import chatserver
> cxn = chatserver.Connection()
> cxn._connect('localhost', 7667)
```

When I do that, I get a log output in the server window indicating that a connection has been made. Good. Then I type

```
> cxn.say('hi')
```

Nothing happens for a while, and then log messages show up for the server and client as expected.

1. Why is this delay ocurring?
2. Am I using the log functionality correctly?
3. I used threading to make it so that I could use the interactive session while the asyncore loop does it's thing for the Connection. Did I do this in a reasonable way?
4. (optional) If I don't include the line `self.out_buffer=""` in the Connection._connect function I get an error saying that .out_buffer does not exist. What's up with this?

```python
import asyncore
import socket
import logging
import threading
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG, format="%(created)-15s %(msecs)d %(levelname)8s %(thread)d %(name)s %(message)s")
log = logging.getLogger(__name__)

class Connection(asyncore.dispatcher_with_send):
    def __init__(self):
        asyncore.dispatcher.__init__(self)

    def _connect(self, host, port, timeout=5, password=None):
        self.host = host
        self.port = port
        self.out_buffer=""
        self.create_socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.connect((host, port))
        #Run the asyncore loop in its own thread so that we can use the interactive session
        self.loop = threading.Thread(target=asyncore.loop)
        self.loop.daemon = True
        self.loop.start()

    def say(self, msg):
        self.out_buffer = msg

    def handle_read(self):
        data = self.recv(4096)
        log.debug('Received %s'%data)

class EchoHandler(asyncore.dispatcher_with_send):

    def handle_read(self):
        log.debug("handle_read")
        data = self.recv(1024)
        log.debug("after recv")
        if data:
            log.debug("got data: %s"%data)
            self.out_buffer = data
        else:
            log.debug("got null data")

class EchoServer(asyncore.dispatcher):
    SOCKET_TYPE = socket.SOCK_STREAM
    ADDRESS_FAMILY = socket.AF_INET
    def __init__(self, host, port):
        self.address = (host,port)
        asyncore.dispatcher.__init__(self)
        self.create_socket(self.ADDRESS_FAMILY, self.SOCKET_TYPE)
        log.debug("bind address=%s %s"%(host,port))
        self.bind(self.address)
        self.listen(1)

    def fileno(self):
        return self.socket.fileno()

    def serve(self):
        asyncore.loop()
        #Start asyncore loop in new thread
#        self.loop = threading.Thread(target=asyncore.loop)
#        self.loop.daemon = True
#        self.loop.start()

    def handle_accept(self):
        """Deal with a newly accepted client"""
        (connSock, clientAddress) = self.accept()
        log.info("conn made: clientAddress=%s %s"%(clientAddress[0], clientAddress[1]))
        #Make a handler for this connection
        EchoHandler(connSock)

    def handle_close(self):
        self.close()
```

Comment: You aren't sending and end of lines with your text, could that be it?

Comment: Tried it. No difference.

Comment: Could be the Nagle algorithm, Google socket option TCP_NODELAY.

Comment: Just tried something interesting: if in Connection._connect I put `self.out_bufer = "some junk"` then as soon as I type `cxn._connect('localhost',7667)` the message goes though. However, subsequent ones put in with `cxn.say` take a long time.

Comment: It's odd that you're mixing async loop with threads. asyncore is not thread safe. http://willpython.blogspot.com/2010/08/multiple-event-loops-with-asyncore-and.html

Comment: The thing is, if I don't put the asyncore loop in its own thread how would I be able to sit in the interactive session and send messages to the server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the problem was as Eero suggested.

I made two changes:

In EchoServer

`asyncore.loop()` to `asyncore.loop(timeout=0.1)`

In Connection

`self.loop = threading.Thread(target=asyncore.loop)` to `self.loop = threading.Thread(target=asyncore.loop, kwargs={'timeout':0.1})`

The response is now much faster. This seems like a hack though so if someone can explain a way to get the same effect in a proper way please contribute.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the asyncore docs you are relying on `asyncore.dispatcher_with_send` to call `send()` and the default timeout for `asyncore.loop()` is 30 seconds. This may explain the delay.

Comment: Ok that's definitely promising but why the heck does the timeout matter here. I must not be triggering something properly.